# Technology stack for UX Development

Tags: ux-field, career-development, learning

I have CS degree, and have been doing programming for a while.

I'm interested in gravitating towards full-stack development, meaning being capable of programming + doing UX Development/ Design work.

People say that in order to transition to more UI work, you should work on UI-centric projects. However, I'm not sure where to start learning. I've seen many UX Design books referenced (Don't Make Me Think, etc) but have not seen UX books or tools/technologies referenced which focus on development.

So, what UX technology stacks do UX developers use to do their work?

P.S - I know that for web HTML/CSS/Javascript is used in front end development, but I already know these technologies and still don't feel like I've gravitated towards being a "UX Developer".

Comment: This is a very open-ended question which is not well suited to UX.SE. For more information on the kinds of questions that belong here, check out [ask]

Comment: UI development is an actual thing (it basically means front end development); UX is a combination of things, including design, analysis and I'd probably say psychology - a UX hire will probably do design, but maybe not graphic design; they may do development or come from that sort of background

Answer (score 3):

That is because there's no such thing as "UX Development". It's a made up term used by companies either looking for a front-end developer and tack on "UX" to the title because the UX market is "hot", or a small firm/startup hoping to hire one person to take on both the UX Designer AND UI developer role.

UX Design is tool/tech agnostic. It's just being aware of your user, putting yourself in their shoes and designing a solution to best address their needs. Often time this means disregarding your current framework of what you're familiar with and start exploring alternatives.

In contrast, development is all about effectiveness and efficiency. How can you architect something to make it run quickly and have it be easy to maintain? Here, the tech stack and framework you choose influences, sometimes even defines, your solution.

They are two very different approaches to problem solving. Both are useful to have. But it's not really something one person can apply at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. From your answer, it seems "UX development" is separated into UX Design and UI Development. UX Design is caring about the user whereas UI Development is implementing the UX Designer's solution.

Comment: @cosmos1990 You got it.

Comment: Here's an article clarifying between the two roles: http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/03/ux-design-versus-ui-development.php